# Emails Not Getting sent with SMTP Server Configured in Gerrit v3.2

Tags: email, smtp, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, gerrithub.io

I have edited gerrits config file with the required SMTP details:

```
 [sendemail]
 enable = true
 smtpServer = smtp.server.com
 smtpServerPort = 25
```

But the thing is, the details somehow don't work upon gerrit but the same values do work upon Jenkins.

There really isnt helpful documentation out there wrt to Gerrit. I even tried to configure the server side of settings for projects config file with:

```
[access]
    inheritFrom = All-Projects
[submit]
    action = inherit
[access "refs/*"]
    owner = blah blah blah
[notify "Administrators"]
    email = blah@blahblahblah.com
```

I tried looking into error logs as well but NOTHING. Any pointers would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Resolved**

The configuration at the gerrit.conf side is just the server side of it.

For the client side, go to `Settings -> Notifications.`

Set notifications for

-> `Project Name: <whichever project you have access to>`

-> `Branch: master`
or any other branch of your choice.

-> `Save Changes`

Once you have configured the notifications, the subscribed events would be sent to you in the form of emails via Gerrit.